# How to make a string in to code

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code)
>   [Run piece of code contained in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string)

is there any way to turn a variable(string) into to a piece of code?
My string has to be changeable (non-static)
If you can explain it simply that would be nice :D

Comment: execute a String as if it is Java-code? No, it is not possible.

Comment: Not clear, please give more info

Comment: what u want to do explain a bit more

Comment: `static` strings can change, too. You mean non-`final`. It's possible, but not easy. Search for [Java Compiler API](http://mike-java.blogspot.de/2008/03/java-6-compiler-api-tutorial.html)

Comment: @Neobonde please always provide an example, it's worth the effort. Do you want to do something like this: `String commands = "int foo = 42; System.out.println(foo);";` and than execute the _code_ within the string?

Comment: Once more, I'd point to the [Java Scripting API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html) for that use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, that you want to create a `String` object with some Java statements and execute the content as if it was a method.

No, it is not possible, because that would imply, that java was an interpreted programming language. Which is not the case.

You could merge the line with some sort of class template (on another string), store it to a file, compile that using the jdk (call javac with `Runtime.exec) and load the class with a custom classloader, then reflect the method and hope for the best.

There is a rather complicated way using the fairly new Java Compiler API, but I guess, that is far beyond your needs. (And there have to be some more complicated tricks, because the eclipse IDE provides views that allow executing Java statements.)