# How to convert a string into a piece of code (Factory Method Pattern?)

Tags: java, design-patterns, groovy, factory

Let's say we have a String like this:

```
String string2code = "variable = 'hello';";
```

How could we convert that String to a piece of code like this?:

```
variable = "hello";
```

Comment: check this question [Run Piece of Code contained in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string)

Comment: Thank you for the link with the solution for Java. I'm using Grails so I can use Java or Groovy. The Groovy solution is easier than the one provided by Java so I marked it as the answer.

Comment: no problem, you are welcom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`GroovyShell`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy) is the answer:

```
String string2code = "variable = 'hello'; return variable.toUpperCase()";

def result = new GroovyShell().evaluate string2code
assert result == "HELLO"
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, it does not work with the querying system of Grails. I posted the new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491301/is-possible-to-convert-a-string-into-a-piece-of-code-in-grails-if-it-includes-a

Answer (score 1):

If you're into more complex stuff later, you can compile whole classes using `GroovyClassLoader`.

```
private static Class loadGroovyClass( File file ) throws MigrationException {
    try {
        GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader( ExternalMigratorsLoader.class.getClassLoader() );

        GroovyCodeSource src = new GroovyCodeSource( file );
        Class clazz = gcl.parseClass( src );
        return clazz;
    }
    catch( CompilationFailedException | IOException ex ){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Good to know, but I just need to compile a piece of code, not the whole class.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can take a look a [Janino](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JANINO/Home)

Janino is a small java compiler than not only can compile source files, it can compile expressions like the one you have.

Comment: Thank you. If I am not wrong, it would be one more solution for Java. @Sniffer wrote the next link with more possibilites for Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string