# Converting a string into a boolean condition

Tags: java, boolean-expression

Say I have a String

```
String strCondition = something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one");
```

How do I convert this String into a boolean condition so that I can be able to use it in an `IF` statement?

If I use `valueOf()`, will it evaluate the contents of the String?

**RE-EDIT:** I am not sure how to put this.

I am taking the value  `something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one")` from a database column. If I try to assign that to `boolean` variable it shows a type mismatch.

Comment: If you have multiple strings but a fixed set of them, then you can go for creating an enum out of them and then comparing them

Comment: Do you mean taking `strCondition` and turning it into code?

Comment: How do you even store the boolean value into a String in the first place?

Comment: This won't even compile. Firstly, `&&` returns type `boolean`. Secondly, `String.contains()` is misspelled.

Comment: I think this could possibly be just a really badly communicated version of "how do I turn a string into code that I can use in a program later?"

Comment: "If I use valueOf(), will it evaluate the contents of the String?" Have you checked the Oracle docs? They might mention it.

Comment: OP: You might want to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string) out. Reflection may or may not be an option, depending on if the structure of `strCondition` is predictable.

Comment: I don't think that even compiles `String strCondition = something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one");`. As mentioned by others the expression is already a `boolean`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you don't.

it already is a boolean expression.

`something.contains("value")` -> this returns either true or false
&&
`somethingElse.equals("one");` -> this also returns true or false.

what you need, is either:

```
boolean strCondition = something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one");
if ( strCondition )
```

or

```
if ( something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one"))
```

EDIT:

The above would either return `true`, `false`, or throw a nasty `NullPointerException`.

To avoid the latter, you should use:

```
if ( "one".equals(somethingElse) && (something != null && something.contains("value"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use these :

```
if (strCondition.equals("true")) 

if (Boolean.getBoolean(strCondition)) 

if (Boolean.valueOf(strCondition))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
something.contains("value") && somethingElse.equals("one");// returns a boolean . why put it into a String in the first place?
```

Answer (score 1):

Read JavaDoc first!

> **[Boolean.valueOf(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)**  returns a Boolean with a value
>   represented by the specified string. The Boolean returned represents a
>   true value if the string argument is not null and is equal, ignoring
>   case, to the string "true".

Sample code

```
if(Boolean.valueOf(strCondition)) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`contains` and equals methods of string returns `boolean` you cannot cast to String