# Convert complex "String" into "Boolean"

Tags: java, string, boolean

I have a condition check resulting in a string value of

`String example = "( (true and true) or (true and false) );`"

I need to convert this string into a boolean value, in this case the result should be **true** or in another example;

`String example = "( (true and true) and (true and false) );"` this should return **false**.

Is there any utility method that I can use to achieve this? Or any other ideas?

Comment: Nope.  You need to write a parser from scratch here.

Comment: I don't know of any library that does this, since I doubt anyone to ever have needed this ..

Comment: that being said you have selected a topic where writing a parser luckily is not that difficult, just 2 to 3 operators, a fixed set of values plus parenthesis.

Comment: Usually you need something more flexible than just evaluating constant boolean expressions, i. e. the input usually contains variables. Existing solutions probably provide more complexity than you need.

Comment: A dirty trick is to use the JavaScript support in the JVM to do that: you just need to replace and and or by && and ||.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks buddy! I did it using the JavaScript `ScriptEngine` that you suggested! You can post an answer if you want.

Comment: Related: [Execute Java code that is stored in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217266/execute-java-code-that-is-stored-in-the-database)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [JEval](http://jeval.sourceforge.net/), though its latest release was a decade ago, and it's a bit sparse in documentation.