# Is it possible to have a function that can download code from a database and execute it as if it belonged to the app itself?

Tags: java, android

Android : What I'm trying to say is, let's say I have an app that has the following function

```
public void FetchCodeAndRun()
{
  ConnectToDatabase();
  String code = FetchCode();
  ExecuteJava(code);
}
```

I'm in need of this method because I would like to modify pieces of code of an app just by changing code in a database

Any help or any other innovative solution to achive this is appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

Comment: This seems like a really bad idea, what is your use-case? There probably is a better way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: I think your design by changing code in database is not very good. And I don't recommend it. However It is possible to execute String as code.

@see this: [Run piece of code contained in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string)

Comment: Oh cool, so if I stored a code in the database as a string and this function can Dowbload and execute, It'll work! Thanks a lot

Comment: If it is ok please accept the answer. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Probably what you are looking for is `BeanShell`: http://www.beanshell.org/manual/embeddedmode.html

You need to add a `bsh-core.jar` in your `/lib` folder and instantiate `Interpreter` object which handles the interpretation of the code you will provide to it.

Here is a guide to do that: http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/06/scripting-your-android-device/