# Is there a java program that can get java syntax from the user and convert it as an output, kinda like mini IDE?

Tags: java

I was wondering if I can make a java program that can act as Java IDE which will take syntax from user and execute it in the terminal. If there is, what are the syntax used to manipulate the compiler and syntax for executing the syntax? Your answers would be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run piece of code contained in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string)

Comment: I flagged the other question because it seems close to what you want, but I would also say that this is a big topic and I'd suggest reading up on it (check out the links in the answers to that question), come up with a plan of action, start implementing, and come back to Stack Overflow when you get stuck on a specific issue :)

Comment: Package [javax.tools](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.compiler/javax/tools/package-summary.html) maybe?

Comment: @MyStackRunnethOver your answer is much appreciated, I'll check into the link and see if it answers what im looking for.