# add String to a List of Objects in Java

Tags: java

```
List<PhoneBook> list = new ArrayList<PhoneBook>();
String str = "new PhoneBook("David","234567");";
```

How can I add (or convert) `str` to code and add it to the list?

I have searched all over the internet, and didn't find anything helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run piece of code contained in a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string)

Comment: In general, you shouldn't. But if you feel you must, that link will help you out.

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. Why do you *want* to doing that?

Comment: i need to convert str to an Object of type PhoneBook and then add it to the List

Comment: str is already given as a String

Answer (score 0):

To convert it to fit the arraylist you've given:

```
List<PhoneBook> list = new ArrayList<>();
PhoneBook not_a_str = new PhoneBook("David","234567");
list.add(not_a_str);
```

To add strings to a list of objects:

```
List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
String str = "new PhoneBook(\"David\",\"234567\")";
list.add(str);
```

To add strings to a list of strings (also objects):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
String str = "new PhoneBook(\"David\",\"234567\")";
list.add(str);
list.add("Anything else");
```

Good luck with java