# get String from api and run it as java code

Tags: java, junit, automation, appium

I have this code I'm scraping from testing tool (in Jira)
in order to cover the Manual Test with Automated tests
so I have some class that make some tests uses the methods which operate some actions

and I succeed scrape the test data from zephyr as as string of the methods
I need a solution in Java how to make these string to act like Java code

that's the strings I scraped from the URL of zephyr api:
for example:

```
"clientUtils().clickOnButton();
browserPageObject().validateBrowserIsOpen();
browserPageObject().closeBrowser();"
```

this block of code could run as itself but I need to infer it to run as Java

much appreciate who help me solve it with easy and qualified way

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389232/run-piece-of-code-contained-in-a-string) seems to have the answer you are looking for

Comment: I don't managed to solve it by you'r answer.
thought there's some simple way to make string to work as Java code