# How to add a custom code to run in a jsp?

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, code-injection

I want to run a custom function in a jsp. And I want to change that function time to time without re-uploading the whole program. how can I do that?
I'm talking about something like uploading the code to a database and executing the code in database when needed. How can I do this in a jsp?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a relevant article [Convert String to Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code)

Some of your options is [javaassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) , [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html) or even go as far as implementing the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) interface.

The choice is up to you