# how to compile java code in android

Tags: java, android, linux

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert String to code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code)

I need to evaluate a string containing valid Java code

eg. I should be able to get `6` from `String code="Math.abs(2*3);";`

Comment: What ??? Do you have any basis in Java programming ?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code

Comment: why dont you just write it in Android?

Comment: 1/ http://whathaveyoutried.com ? 2/ do you have any notion of java compilation ?

Comment: Question is ok, why you downvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like quite an interesting idea, can I ask what the purpose of your application will be?

The best bet is to build up a dictionary of known patterns you will support.

My first idea is that you should create an **ArrayList** of accepted patterns. So for example:

```
ArrayList<String> acceptedPatterns = new ArrayList<String>();
acceptedPatterns.add("math.abs");
acceptedPatterns.add("math.acos");
```

etc.

Then you can evaluate this list when you get hold of the string.

```
String foundPattern = null;
String myStringFromInput = editText.getText();
for (String pattern : acceptedPatterns){
  if (myStringFromInput.contains(pattern){
     // we have recognised a java method, flag this up
     foundPattern = pattern;
     break;
  }
}
```

At this point you would have "Math.abs" in your **foundPattern** variable.

You could then use your knowledge of how this method works to compute it. I can't think of a super efficient way, but a basic way that would at least get you going would be something like a big if/else statement:

```
int result = 0;
if (foundPattern.contains("Math.abs"){
   result = computeMathAbs(myStringFromInput);
}else if (foundPattern.contains("Math.acos"){
   // etc
}
```

And then in your **computeMathAbs** method you would do something like this:

```
private int computeMathAbs(String input){
   int indexOfBracket = input.indexOf("(");
   int indexOfCloseBracket = input.indexOf(")");
   String value = input.subString(indexOfBracket,indexOfCloseBracket);
   int valueInt = computeFromString(value);
   int result = Math.abs(valueInt);
   return result;
}
```

You could then display the result passed back.

The **computeFromString()** method will do a similar thing, looking for the * symbol or other symbols and turning this into a multiplication like the abs example.

Obviously this is a basic example, so you would only be able to compute one java method at a time, the complexity for more than one method at a time would be quite difficult to program I think.

You would also need to put quite a bit of error handling in, and recognise that the user might not enter perfect java. Can of worms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Groovy` http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Eval.html

```
import groovy.util.Eval;

... 

    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put("a", 2);
    params.put("b", 3);

    Integer res = (Integer) Eval.me("param", params, "Math.abs(param.a * param.b)");

    System.out.println("res with params = " + res);

    System.out.println("res without params = " + Eval.me("Math.abs(2*3)"));
```