# Want to convert a string as the coding convention

Tags: java, swing

I want to create a program to format a string into a code(As the Java coding convention). I tried with this.

```
final JEditorPane codeEditor = new JEditorPane();
JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(codeEditor);
c.add(scrPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
codeEditor.setContentType("text/java");
codeEditor.setText("public static void main(String[] args) {\n}");
```

This is actually working for typing on the pane. How can I improve this code to format my string when I press a button. Such as...

```
class A{
   public static void main(String args[]){
   System.out.println("A");
   }
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code

Comment: You'll probably have to write your own string formatter with your preferred coding style.

Comment: this is possible with two separate JVM instances, by using 5-6 diff. resources

Comment: mKobrel - I didn't get you.