# Boolean expression should be evaluated at runtime in a timer, reacting to changes in the swing gui

Tags: java, swing, timer

Here is what I am trying to do: I have a swing gui with two JFrames. The first has a JCheckBox and the second displays some text. Also the second has a javax.swing.Timer that is waiting for the checkbox in the first frame to be clicked. Once it is clicked, some more text is to be displayed. It works if I have only one condition (click the checkbox) and the condition is directly in the if-statement, like this:

```
javax.swing.Timer timer = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if ( otherGUI.jCheckBox.isSelected() ){
            //add some text to second JFrame
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
});
```

Now for the twist: This should happen not only once, but multiple times. There is an ArrayList of timers, each with its own text and condition, one starting after the other. My problem is: If I store the conditions as strings in an ArrayList, they seem to be evaluated once at the start of the programme, so the condition from above stays false, even when I click the checkbox. Here is my actual code:

```
    SomeGUI gui = new SomeGUI();

    ArrayList<javax.swing.Timer> timer = new ArrayList<javax.swing.Timer>();
    ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> cond = new ArrayList<String>();

    text.add("some text");
    cond.add("gui.jCheckBox.isSelected()");

    text.add("some more text");
    cond.add(new Condition("true"));

    //etc.

    for ( int i = 0; i < text.size() - 1; i++  ){
        int j = i;//not sure why this trick is necessary. i doesn't work later on
        timer.add( new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                boolean bool = false;
                try{
                    bool = Boolean.parseBoolean( cond.get(j) );
                }
                catch(Exception ex){}
                if ( bool ){
                    addText(p, text.get(j+1));
                    timer.get(j).stop();
                    timer.get(j+1).start();
                }
            }
        }));
    }
    timer.get(0).start();
```

I already tried an `ArrayList<Boolean>` for the conditions to the same effect. The code above just represents my present state of trial and error.
I hope that I could make clear what I am trying to achieve. So how can I store boolean expressions in a list/array and have them evaluated in an if-statement again and again at runtime and not only once when the programme is started?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: *Don’t* use trial and error when programming. Read the [documentation of the methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Boolean.html#parseBoolean(java.lang.String)) you are about to use to learn what they do.

Comment: And just in case: let me know if there is anything else I can do to make my answer upvote worthy in your eyes. But no hurry - I hit the daily limit already today so upvotes no longer count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple "evaluation" of strings in Java. It is possible, but really not "java style". See [Convert String to Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code)

One other option would be that your strings represent method names (which exist on a well known object); then you could use reflection to invoke that method based on the provided string. But also, pretty ugly.