# Write a Java Program That Allows Users to Input Their Own Formula and Calculates It

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program (which is part of an assignment) which allows users to input their own function, and then the program calculates it and gets a value.
I have actually written a program that calculates an IVP (Initial Value Problem)  using the Euler-Cauchy method. My initial function was -2*t*u^2.
However, what if I want to work on 4*t*u^3 instead or some other formula?

I tried getting the formula as String from the user, but I am having difficulty in matching a particular variable (e.g. t or u) to a number.

Comment: Why are you "having difficulty in matching a particular variable"? Could you be a little more specific? Can you post the code?

Comment: is this formula has the same form every time or it can be any formula user type?

Comment: /*
  *Let me use this to see if i can clarify 
  */
 //Taking for example a formula input which is the product of u and t 
String input = "u * t";

// Assume i got the value of u & t through scanner or some other io
int u=5, t= 3;

// how  can i make my program know that u=5 should be multiplied by t=3 based on the user formula

System.out.println(input);

Comment: You can use String's replace function if that is what you're looking for. For example, to replace the u in the string "u * t", you can do String.replace("u", u). The "u" is the "u" in the string and the u (with no quotes) is the integer variable.

Comment: This might help at some point: [Evaluating a math expression given in string form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3422673)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`String.replace()` function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(char,%20char)) to convert the `u` and `t` from the formula string to the actual variables, then take a good look at this Stack Overflow question: [Convert String to Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/935175/convert-string-to-code)